# define server paths in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter's in there **MY_Loader.php** I would like to be able to define a couple of directory server paths admin and also main url.

`HTTP_SERVER` for admin url and `HTTP_CATALOG` for main url

Admin has its own app folder and index.php its a sub directory.

I have tried `$this->config->item('base_url')` but did not work.

**MY_loader.php** This my loader based in admin sub directory.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/hmvc/loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

public function __construct() { 

// Get The Admin Url Example //  http://localhost/project/admin
//define('HTTP_SERVER');

// Get The Front/Main Url Example //  http://localhost/project/
//define('HTTP_CATALOG');

$this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'views/template/' => TRUE);
$this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
$this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
$this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
$this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);

log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");
}  
}
```

Comment: have you define urls in config? try base_url()

Answer (score 0):

You can create file **path.cfg** in **config** folder

```
$config['admin_path'] = 'http://localhost/project/admin/';
$config['front_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';`
```

and then load config in controller

```
$this->load->config('path');
```

Comment: But on my config file I use `$config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;` because I have a function on `index.php` that just lets me do that so don't have to type in full url I have same on both `index.php's`

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use inbuilt functions for path :-

`base_url()`  or `site_url()`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/'; // or keep null for default
$config['adminpath'] = 'http://example.com/admin';

$this->config->item('adminpath');
```

or use admin path like

```
$adminpath = base_url().'admin/';
```

Comment: As said above. But on my config file I use $config['base_url'] = BASE_URL; because I have a function on index.php that just lets me do that so don't have to type in full url I have same on both index.php's I have admin as own sub directory with own app and index.php

Comment: so keep null in both base_url and call base_url()

Comment: then create a constant.php/custom_config.php and add in autoload.php

Comment: I am trying to be able to do it all in MY_Loader trying to avoid having to create another file.

Comment: This here gets it to the main `$SERVER_URL = config_item('base_url'); $HTTP_SERVER = explode('/', $SERVER_URL); $myLastElement = end($HTTP_SERVER); $admin = str_replace("admin/","",$SERVER_URL);` But need something simular for admin url because when call base url it show page load error.